# What is the proper way to use string::find to look for a word?

Tags: c++

How would I look through a string for a word rather then each character in that word. I have my code here and it always seems to find everything that is .obj even if its o or b or j or "." I checked the docuementation [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) but was unable to find an answer. Here is my code:

```
 string &str = *it;

 if(it->find(".obj"))
 {
     cout << "Found .Obj" << endl;
 }
```

I also tried to use `string::compare` but that failed.

Comment: Show the whole code; ie. what 'it' is. Also, the return value is NOT true or false based on whether the substring was found - read the docs again.

Comment: have you tried just using .substring(".obj")

Answer (score 8):

`find` does search for the full text string that you pass as the function argument.  What you're misunderstanding is the return value;  `find` doesn't return true or false for whether or not it found the string you requested;  it returns the index in the string where it found your requested substring, or `std::string::npos` if no match was found.

So for example:

```
std::string a = "foobar.obj";
std::string b = "baz.obj";
std::string c = "qux";
std::string d = ".obj";

a.find(".obj") == 6
b.find(".obj") == 3
c.find(".obj") == std::string::npos // not found
d.find(".obj") == 0
```

When interpreted as a boolean value, any integer other than 0 is treated as "true" -- even the "not found" std::string::npos value.  Which is, I think, what has you confused.

So in your "if" statement, then, instead of:

```
if (it->find(".obj"))
```

You want to be testing:

```
if (it->find(".obj") != std::string::npos)
```

Comment: Ty trevor :) i shall remeber to look at the return value from now on